# use isMemberOf by group name in Azure AD Graph API

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

As part of an Azure AD Graph call, I have the following `request.Content`:

```
var requestString = "{\"groupId\":\"xxxx\",\"memberId\":\"yyyy\"}";
request.Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Where `xxxx` is the guid of the group and `yyyy` is the guid of the user. This works. Returns true.

Now I would like to be able to send a similar request that sends the *names* of the group and the user instead of guids. That is:

```
var requestString = "{\"groupId\":\"webdevs\",\"memberId\":\"bob\"}";
request.Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

This call does not work and I realize this might not be possible. Maybe I need to fetch the guids by the user/group names, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IsMemberOf REST only supports to request using the groupId and memberId like below:
[image]

You were right, we can get the groupId first via the group name then call this REST API to check the membership. And we can use the $filter parameter in the REST like below get the guids of user/group via their name:

```
Get https://graph.windows.net/adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/groups?api-version=1.6&$filter=displayName+eq+'GroupName'

Get https://graph.windows.net/adb2cfei.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=displayName+eq+'UserName’
```

You can refer this REST about more detail from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf).